# Creating a GUI application for creating graphs

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, pipe

I want to create an application with a python user interface for windows.

The purpose of the project is to build a graphical and mathematical model of the thermal network circuit and hydraulic calculation. The application should provide the user with a tool for creating pipeline diagrams (the diagram will consist of a source, consumers, routes, nodes).

The scheme should be logically connected and will resemble a tree that has a trunk, branches and leaves.

I mean that the user will draw the lines of the trunk and branches, so nodes will form at the points where the lines intersect. Then the user will set the location points of the consumer subscribers at the endpoints of the branches. Each element is supposed to have a set of parameters for further calculation. An important characteristic of the scheme should be its interactivity. For example, the user should be able to change this scheme, delete and add elements.
in the end, you should get a coherent interactive scheme with the logic of the tree.

My question. Which libraries should I use to implement my task? I consider Tkinter to be the simplest library, but I don't know if it will allow me to implement these functions.

I am newbie. This will be my first full application.

So far I'm familiar with tkinter at a basic level. I tried to create canvas buttons and functionality for drawing objects without combining them into a related diagram

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.